# Body physics and jiggling for iclone characters

Tags: rigging, bones, physics, import

I want to bring my animated iclone characters into blender so I can add clothes and props and then render 3d VR.
I want jiggling in the chest and butt for added realism but iclone characters have no butt bones.
Is it possible to add them in Blender?
What's the best way to do this for a newbie?
Would I have to rig them again in blender and if I did would that mean my animation and facial mocap becomes unusable?

Comment: You can deform existing mesh, rigged mesh included without too much bother in Blender.  Try "Cage Rigging" or the Lattice deform modifier on those sections that are to 'wobble'.  I've just tried the former on an iClone character and it looks a bit too realistic to post up here, lol.  Also, you may need to add a little more mesh/vertices to the model in those areas beforehand.

Comment: Ok thanks. I remember experimenting with a lattice modifier before.  I thought it was in Maya but it could have been blender.

Comment: I'm still trying to familiarize myself with blenders layout and how to get things done.  It seems to be running very slow with my iclone character loaded. If I go to the animation tab click on another area of the time slider it takes about 5 or 10 seconds to load up that frame. Pressing play is pretty much useless. Don't know if this is normal when working with an iclone character in blender or if my animation is too long or if it's my settings.

Comment: If you haven't tried this already, try running the viewport in 'Solid' mode. That should speed thing up. You might also like to check on the number of vertices you're running.  Commercially produced characters tend to be a lot more complex.  There is a 'Decimate' modifier in Blender that I've never tried to use seriously.  I think it's supposed to simplify models.

Comment: Cont...
To see how 'Cage Rigging' works you could just stand a cylinder up on it's end and give it the gender attributes required, try and 'wobble' that/those.  Cage-R is very effective once you get to know it and not demanding on your machine either.

Comment: Thanks. I had an older version of blender and after updating it seems much faster. What will these methods react to?  If I use cage or lattice does it work based on gravity?  I also just bought simply cloth.  It looks amazing for someone like me.  Is there any way to use that to create bouncing skin? They have some pretty easy to use presets but maybe I'm asking for too much.

Comment: With a cage rig I almost always use a 'hook' to deform some of the cage's vertices. A hook can be parented to a physics enabled object so yes, it could react to gravity etc. Frankly, the bouncing you're seeking would be easier to do by hand - keyframing.  You only have to do a full cycle or two, then loop it.  I'll redo my iClone example on a simpler and less realistic model.  Will leave a link to the video.

Comment: That would be great. I pretty much forget everything I learned about blender before.  I don't mind key framing if I can make it look natural.

Comment: I've placed the videos onto 1-Drive ready for viewing but from your last comment it sounds like you need the Blend file, so I'll post it up as an answer.  The vers I'm using is 2.77 but the deforming method is fairly universal.

Comment: Cool. That looks pretty good. I'll try to get it set up properly.  I assume the graph editor is similar to using the curve editor in iclone to give a more realistic motion between keyframes? It looks simple enough. Thanks.

Comment: The graph editor is one of the most amazing and useful features about Blender and almost a science in it's own right.  In fact just about everything in Blender runs rings around the commercial stuff when it comes to flexibility and control over what you're doing.  Good luck with your 'wobbles'.  :)

Answer (score 2):

This a highly simplified version of what can be done with a proper model.
The Blend file is below... (Vers 2.77)

[image]

Cage deforming is used here.  That uses the 'Mesh Deform' Modifier with a simple cube named as the cage.

[image]

The cage (cube) is deformed at it's rear vertices only and that deform's the model's rearmost vertices more than those further forward.  i.e. the more distant the model's vertices, the less the effect, hence the soft-body (wobbling) reaction.

-==========-

Warning - Cage rigging can act on vertices outside the cage so it would be advisable to create a vertice group, nominate ONLY those vertices to be affected.  That guarantees no gate crashers.

-==========-

The hook's motion was keyframed and those f-curves were further shaped in the Graph editor to emulate physics behavior.

If you're not inclined to keyframe manually, you may be able to bounce a ball and parent the hook to that, bake the hook's movements and loop the first cycle.

[image]